# Bootstrap 3 glyphicon white background

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

What is the incantation to make a glyphicon have a white background instead of the normal, in bootstrap 3, gray one?  Surely they have built this in and I just haven't found it yet.   In general I am experiencing a lot of pain switching an existing angularjs project to bootstrap 3. Many seemingly arbitrary differences.

Note this is for making the background "white" not the icon itself.  A related question is whether there is a built in way to get a transparent background for a glyphicon.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own custom CSS style.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-custom" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-custom {  
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #CCCCCC;
    color: #333333;
 }
.btn-custom:hover {
   background-color: #000;
   border-color: #fff;
   color: #333333;
}
```

Here's a fiddle - http://www.bootply.com/pmyZvM3iOq

To make the background transparent; simply use `background-color: transparent;`